# vmplayer never keep virtual machines on library?

Tags: permissions, vmware, virtualization

I have installed "Vmplayer(version 6.0.2 build-1744117)" on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I have created 3 virtual machines on my home directory. When i open vmplayer, library always empty and every time i have to browse and select them to open. I tried different folder permissions and it didn't help. current **folder permission** is **755** and **owner** is current user(me).

How do i keep my vms on library, any idea? thanks.

Comment: Do you have your /run directory in a ram partition?

Comment: No Sir, /run is located on / partition and i didn't have deep knowledge about ram partitions and this is just fresh Ubuntu installation partitions(/,/home and SWAP).